# How about searching Google with Selenium?

Tags: java

I want to search something on Google using Selenium chromedriver and enter it. I can normally do this within the site, but I couldn't type it into google. What code can we use for this?

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@class='desktopOldAutosuggestTheme-UyU36RyhCTcuRs_sXL9b']")).sendKeys("HBCV00000ODHHV");

Fakat olmadı.

Comment: the `class` attribute looks like it's using some autogenerated name. That is not a reliable way to identify that input field since that name will change.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do so is via the url when you perform driver.get(...).

Look at the google url for `german shepards`: https://www.google.com/search?q=german+shepards .

If you want to go the google.com and type in the search box you need to perform a better xpath query then by class name. As mentioned by @f1sh this is because google generates the class names (for scope based css). For me the following works for the search bar.

```py
search_bar : WebElement = driver.get_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@title='Search']")

# then you can perform the send_keys
search_bar.send_keys(...)
```

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is not the search text because I tried too many terms and it didn't work.
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@class='desktopOldAutosuggestTheme-UyU36RyhCTcuRs_sXL9b']")).sendKeys("HBCV00000ODHHV");
   driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@class='desktopOldAutosuggestTheme-UyU36RyhCTcuRs_sXL9b']")).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);

these are just an example on different sites. I tried id class type as xpath in every way, but it didn't write the text I wrote in the search bar.

Comment: sendKeys(....) is not the problem. `findElements` is your problem. Read my answer carefully. After too many google searches, google give you captchas. Maybe you are getting blocked by those?

Comment: Also try debugging your code. Don't directly use sendKeys(...) but first do findElement, and print some values that belong to the element, to see if you have the correct WebElement.